# Problema con el PHP Undefined index:

Tags: php, html, mysql

como soy nuevo con el manejo de php  me salio un error que no pude arreglar, el error que me salto es este "Undefined index: color". Les dejo el HTML, Lo que quiero hacer yo es que del select tomar el valor elegido y subirlo a la base de datos para poder tener un registros de los pedidos que me encargan en la pagina.

```html
<form action="pedidosBuzos.php" class="formularioB formulario">
        <label for="" class="formulario__label">Color del Buzo</label>
        <select name="color" id="" class="formulario__input">
            <option SELECTED>Seleccionar color</option>
            <option value="negro">Negro</option>
            <option value="blanco">Blanco</option>
            <option value="rojo">Rojo</option>
            <option value="bordo">Bordo</option>
            <option value="azul">Azul</option>
        </select>
        <label for="" class="formulario__label">Talle</label>
        <select name="talla" id="" class="formulario__input">
            <option SELECTED>Seleccionar Talle</option>
            <option value="s">S</option>
            <option value="m">M</option>
            <option value="l">L</option>
            <option value="xl">XL</option>
            <option value="xxl">XXL</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" class="formulario__submit" value="Pedir">
    </form>
```

En el PHP lo que hice fue capturar los datos mediante el metodo POST y desde ahi insertarlo en la base de datos, Lo que no entiendo es que procedimiento hice mal. Desde ya les agradesco su ayuda.

Mi código PHP que procesa la información

```
<?php 

include 'cn.php'; 

$color = $_POST['color']; 
$talla = $_POST['talla']; 
$prenda = 'buzo'; 

$insertar = "INSERT INTO pedi(color, talla, sexo, prenda) 
             VALUES ('$prenda', '$color', '$talla')"; 
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar); 

if (!$resultado)
{ 
    echo '<script> alert("Error del pedido"); window.location = "Buzos.html" </script>'; 
}else{ 
    echo '<script> alert("Pedido realizado"); window.location = "IndexBuzos.html" </script>'; 
} 
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: agrega el código PHP que usas para recibir los valores

Comment: <?php
include 'cn.php';

$color = $_POST['color'];
$talla = $_POST['talla'];
$prenda = 'buzo';

$insertar = "INSERT INTO pedi(color, talla, sexo, prenda) VALUES ('$prenda',  '$color', '$talla')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
if (!$resultado){
    echo '<script>
        alert("Error del pedido");
        window.location = "Buzos.html"
    </script>';
} else{
    echo '<script>
        alert("Pedido realizado");
        window.location = "IndexBuzos.html"
    </script>';
}
mysqli_close($conexion);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso ocurre por que en tu formulario olvidaste indicar el `method` a usar; es decir en este caso hacer esto

```
<form action="pedidosBuzos.php" method="POST">
```

Ya que tu en tu archivo `.php` estas indicando que esperas recibir 2 valores enviados por ese verbo HTTP pero en tu formulario no lo indicas, entonces solo agrégalo y funcionará

Para que consultes mas sobre el tema, aquí te dejo una fuente oficial

- [Trabajo con formualrios](https://www.php.net/manual/es/tutorial.forms.php)